# InterVLAN routing on Cisco router with multiple trunks

Tags: cisco, routing, router, vlan

I recently came across a scenario where I wanted to (ab)use a Cisco router (ISR 4331) as a layer 3 switch.
The router is directly connected to two switches. The connection between each switch and the router is a trunk port with VLAN 10 and 11 configured and allowed.
VLAN 10 is used for network 10.10.10.0/24 and VLAN 11 is 10.10.11.0/24.
[image]

On a layer 3 switch one would now configure the ports as trunk ports (`switchport mode trunk`) and then assign an IP to the VLAN interfaces 10 an 11. With `ip routing` enabled the switch would then handle the interVLAN routing and the VLAN IPs could be used as default gateway for the PCs.

However one can't use the switchport command on a router port, so I tried to create subinterfaces (like one would for a router on a stick setup) for each port + VLAN and used the encapsulation command. I did not assign a IP address to the subinterfaces because then I would need to assign IPs twice (for each physical interface) which would error out with

```
% 10.10.10.0 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/0/1.10
```

when trying to assign 10.10.10.1 to GigabitEthernet0/0/2.10.
So I instead I assigned 10.10.10.1 to interface VLAN10 and 10.10.11.1 to interface VLAN11.
However the IPs would not be reachable and checking with the simulation mode of PacketTracer I could see that the router would discard the ARP packet of the PC with the error

```
6. The receiving port does not have an IP address.
```

[image: ARP drop]
I think this is happening because IOS expects the router (sub)interface itself to have an IP address assigned and assigning an IP to a VLAN only works for switchports.
I actually tried inserting a switch module into the router (NIM-ES2-4) and with that I was able to get the interVLAN routing to work by now being able to use the switchport command on these ports.

However im now wondering if its somehow possible to make the router ports behave like switch ports so that interVLAN routing can be done without inserting a switch module or adding a third switch and doing a classic router on a stick setup with a single trunk to the router.

Comment: Routers route between networks, not from a network back to the same network. Routers are not switches, but you can get a switch module to put in some routers. Alternatively, you can use IRB (BVIs, not SVIs).

Comment: Also, look at [this answer from Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/254347/what-is-a-cisco-bvi-interface-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: The linked answer and comments did indeed help. Packet Tracer doesn't seems to support the bridging so I will have to test with some hardware / GNS3 but IRB seems to be the answer to the problem.